# How do I clone a single branch in Git?

Tags: git, branch, git-clone

I have a local Git repository in `~/local_repo`. It has a few branches:

```
$ git branch
* master
  rails
  c
  c++
```

To clone the local repository, I do:

```
$ git clone ~/local_repo new_repo
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/new_repo/.git/
```

The `new_repo` master branch points to the `local_repo` master branch, and I can push / pull.

But I am unable to clone another branch. I want to only pull the branch I want (e.g. `rails`), so that the new repository has a `master` branch that pushes to and pulls from `local_repo`'s `rails` branch, by default. How do I accomplish this, or perhaps something similar with `local_repo` tracking the master `local_repo`?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` show?

Comment: Would `git checkout -b newbranch origin/branchiwant` works better? (without the `--track`option)

Comment: I think what you are trying to do there is a bad idea. Use different repositories for different projects. Branches are something completely different.

Comment: @Manni, I was kind of thinking that, since git didn't seem to like what I'm doing. Can you explain why? Is it because branches shouldn't be long lived?

Comment: @Jakub, `git branch -a` shows the same thing as the `git branch` above.

Comment: @rodarmor git branch shows the list of active branches & git branch -a shows all the branches after cloning any repo.

Comment: @rodarmor I think what you are trying to do there is a good idea, and I had exactly this question.

Comment: Its more a matter of opinion.  Google keeps all their code in a [single repository](https://www.wired.com/2015/09/google-2-billion-lines-codeand-one-place/).  That being said, I agree with @innaM.  This type of workflow is difficult to manage especially when trying streamline version control operations.

Answer (score 1154, accepted):

Note: the **[git1.7.10](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/3/28/418) (April 2012)** actually allows you to **clone only one branch**:

```bash
# clone only the remote primary HEAD (default: origin/master)
git clone <url> --single-branch

# as in:
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch <folder>
```

Note:

- `<url>` is the URL of the remote repository, and does not reference the branch cloned
- `<folder>` is the local folder where you want to clone the repository

You can see it in [`t5500-fetch-pack.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/06dd2baa8da4a73421b959ec026a43711b9d77f9/t/t5500-fetch-pack.sh#L123):

> ```bash
> test_expect_success 'single branch clone' '
>   git clone --single-branch "file://$(pwd)/." singlebranch
> '
> ```

[Tobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229753/tobu) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git/9920956?noredirect=1#comment27508922_9920956) that:

> **This is implicit when doing a shallow clone.
>
> This makes `git clone --depth 1` the easiest way to save bandwidth.**

And since Git 1.9.0 (February 2014), shallow clones support data transfer (push/pull), so that option is even more useful now.
See more at "[Is `git clone --depth 1` (shallow clone) more useful than it makes out?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309)".

---

"Undoing" a shallow clone is detailed at "[Convert shallow clone to full clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17937889/6309)" (git 1.8.3+)

> ```bash
> # unshallow the current branch
> git fetch --unshallow
>
> # for getting back all the branches (see Peter Cordes' comment)
> git config remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git fetch --unshallow
> ```

As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1308967/chris) comments:

> the magic line for getting missing branches to reverse `--single-branch` is (git v2.1.4):
>
> ```bash
> git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git fetch --unshallow
> ```

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), "`git clone --recurse-submodules --single-branch`" **now uses the same single-branch option when cloning the submodules**.

See [commit 132f600](https://github.com/git/git/commit/132f600b060c2db7fd3d450dfadb6779a61c648a), [commit 4731957](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47319576f112b60ecd85930d162cd7656132fd0d) (21 Feb 2020) by [Emily Shaffer (`nasamuffin`)](https://github.com/nasamuffin).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b22db26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b22db265d6bde72391c8d47700dc781a3ea2ae41), 05 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`clone`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/132f600b060c2db7fd3d450dfadb6779a61c648a): pass --single-branch during --recurse-submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emily Shaffer</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> Previously, performing "`git clone --recurse-submodules --single-branch`" resulted in submodules cloning all branches even though the superproject cloned only one branch.
>
> Pipe `--single-branch` through the submodule helper framework to make it to '`clone`' later on.

Comment: `git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch <folder>` works like a charm.

Comment: Yup, I think it's time to update the accepted answer :)
This does "work like a charm"

Comment: Also, this is implicit when doing a shallow clone.  This makes `clone --depth 1` the easiest way to save bandwidth.

Comment: @Tobu and VonC `--depth 1` is unsafe for the user because they may wish to actually push/pull with the new clone.

Comment: to get other branches, change the fetch= line in .git/config.  Replace the branch name with *.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802145/convert-shallow-clone-to-full-clone, I put a more detailed comment there.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok, I have included the unshallow process in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Would not the refspec be better if it had a plus in front of it? I.e. `git config remote.origin.fetch  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: @KlasMellbourn I don't know if it would be "better", but it would enable `push --force`.

Comment: Thanks for the description of how to undo — that's what I actually came here to find out.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for the awesome thing: git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch <folder> woking for me... :-)

Comment: How to update this `single-branch` repo? it's fetching all the other branches when I try to perform `git pull` :(

Comment: @mat if you cloned the repo with the single branch option, the refspec associated to fetch should only be for one branch, not all branches.

Comment: @VonC Well, this is a huge repo cloned with: `git clone git@github.com:odoo/odoo.git --branch 10.0 --depth 1 --single-branch` and it counts 22641 objects. When I try to pull it counts 300k+ :( The 10.0 branch size is 114.62 MiB and the pull is 600Mb+

Comment: I was able to update my single branch repo with: `git fetch origin branch --depth 1` then `git reset --hard origin/branch` as I'm not interested on merge anything :)

Comment: Just to spell out Peter Cordes' correction in full, the magic line for getting missing branches to reverse `--single-branch` is `git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` and `git fetch --unshallow` (git v2.1.4)

Comment: @Chris Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: [Here I just added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63761209/4561887) to expound upon the series of individual and more-common git commands one can run to obtain the `-b branch_name` and `--single-branch` effects while `git clone`ing.

Comment: Is it possible to get back to full repository? I cloned recnetly single branch, I believe like that `git clone <url> --single-branch` and now if I type git checkout origin/<another_known_branch> I receive _error: pathspec 'origin/<branch-name>' did not match any file(s) known to git_. The only branch weights about 4 Gb, so it could take a lot of time to re-clone the whole repo again. So how can I turn --single-branch to a regular whole repo clone?

Comment: @kolyaseg You can change the refspec ([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811337/6309)): see the  [`git config` command here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23780060/6309). Or you can add a new branch with [`git remote set-branch --add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-branchesem)), as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70993964/6309).

Answer (score 699):

One way is to execute the following.

```bash
git clone user@git-server:project_name.git -b branch_name /your/folder
```

Where `branch_name` is the branch of your choice and "/your/folder" is the destination folder for that branch. It's true that this will bring other branches giving you the opportunity to merge back and forth.

**Update**

Now, starting with Git 1.7.10, you can now do this

```bash
git clone user@git-server:project_name.git -b branch_name --single-branch /your/folder
```

Comment: This works, but it fetches *all* branches. See @frerich=raabe's answer below.

Comment: Thanks you. only add "-b branch_name" in my case. It saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly...! I am more of a TFS person and for my personal projects have been using git. W.r.to git branching, I was doing it the wrong way earlier and good to know this easy method and it seems perfect! Thanks again! Already +1'd, if possible I would give +100 :)

Comment: add --single-branch to reduce bandwidth

Comment: You can also add `--single-branch` to fetch only the history associated with this branch instead of all history & tags the repository contains.

Comment: @AlexNolasco Can you please edit the answer saying what is **/some/folder** ? Thank you

Comment: @NabinKhadka i've clarified as suggested

Answer (score 115):

Using Git version 1.7.3.1 (on Windows), here's what I do (`$BRANCH` is the name of the branch I want to checkout and `$REMOTE_REPO` is the URL of the remote repository I want to clone from):

```
mkdir $BRANCH
cd $BRANCH
git init
git remote add -t $BRANCH -f origin $REMOTE_REPO
git checkout $BRANCH
```

The advantage of this approach is that subsequent `git pull` (or `git fetch`) calls will also just download the requested branch.

Comment: Whats the different between your script and this line? `git clone -b $BRANCH $REMOTE_REPO $BRANCH` afik they are the same?

Comment: @Ian: One difference is that `git clone -b` gives you all remote refs (all remote branches and tags) as `git branch -a` shows. With my script, you just get a single ref.

Comment: When I try the above (say with $BRANCH="nick"), I get 'fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/nick'. Doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: Note that `-t $BRANCH` works even without `-f`, which would fetch immediately. Then, `git fetch origin` would fetch, and `git checkout $BRANCH` would establish the local branch and checkout. That is useful when you need to configure the remote before fetching, e.g. `git config remote.origin.uploadpack=/bin/upload-pack`.

Comment: As I'm on an "old" corporate git (1.6.0.2) I'm bound to above solution. I had same problem as @Nick. Executing git `branch -a` showed `origin/$BRANCH`. Doing `git checkout origin/$BRANCH` fixed this.

Answer (score 34):

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch
```

Just put in URL and branch name.

Answer (score 33):

You can try the long-winded way:

```
mkdir newrepo.git
cd newrepo.git
git init
git remote add origin file:///path/to/original
git fetch origin branchiwant:refs/remotes/origin/branchiwant
git checkout -b branchiwant --track origin/branchiwant
```

What this does is:

- Create and init an empty Git repository.
- Adds the original repository as a remote called *origin*.
- Fetches only the branch you require from the remote called *origin*.
- Creates and checks out a new branch that is set up to track the source branch you just cloned.

Hopefully that will be something like what you are after.

Comment: The arguments to git remote add are swapped, but I couldn't then get checkout to work. "git checkout origin/rails" gave me "error: pathspec 'origin/rails' did not match any file(s) known to git." and the alternative gave me "fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches."

Comment: @rodarmor: have corrected the git remote command, thanks.  Can you paste the output of `git branch -r`?

Comment: @jkp, Actually `git branch -r` gives no output.

Comment: @rodarmor: I've corrected the example and this definitely works (tested).  HTH (you can accept it once tested it you like ;))

Comment: the -b switch is relatively new. Last time I ran it on a debian squeeze it wasn't available, IIRC

Comment: the last cmd should be: git checkout -b branchiwant --track remotes/branchiwant

Answer (score 27):

You can do it by using the below command:

```
git clone -b branch_name --single-branch project_url local_folder_to_clone_in
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I actually had problem in Source Tree to clone a single branch, thus did it manually

Answer (score 20):

From [git-clone man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

**`--single-branch`** is your friend during clone
remember to use with `--branch <branch name>` or only remote primary HEAD will be cloned (master by default)

Always remember to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to read fresh source, not the one from cache :-)
(I didn't so didn't know about this option for long time.)

Comment: git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch <folder>

Answer (score 10):

Clone only one branch. This is the easiest way:

```
git clone -b BRANCH_NAME --single-branch git@bitbucket.org:___/PROJECTNAME.git
```

Answer (score 7):

There are ample answers here which mention:

1. Download **1** branch (*with* the `--single-branch` part):

   ```sh
   # (We'll refer to this as "the 1st command" below.)
   # 1. Clone ONLY `branch_name`, then check it out. The `--single-branch` part
   #    means that ONLY `branch_name` is cloned, fetched, pulled, and
   #    tracked. _No other remote branches will be cloned to your PC
   #    whatsoever._
   git clone -b branch_name --single-branch \
   https://github.com/some_project/some_project.git
   ```

   ...or some version of that, and a few which mention just:
2. Download **all** branches (withOUT the `--single-branch` part):

   ```sh
   # (We'll refer to this as "the 2nd command" below.)
   # 2. Clone ALL remote branches, then `git checkout` the `branch_name`
   #    branch.
   git clone -b branch_name \
   https://github.com/some_project/some_project.git
   ```

**But, I'd like to expound upon these two things a bit and show a more familiar set of *equivalent commands* so we can see what is happening with each under-the-hood.**

Let's assume that you have a remote repo on GitHub at https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus.git, with remote branches `master` and `version_2.5` (this is a real example you can actually run right now).

## Breakdown of the 2nd command from above:

**The 2nd command** (`git clone -b version_2.5 https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus.git`) clones ALL REMOTE BRANCHES to your local PC, but then checks out the `version_2.5` branch instead of the `master` branch. That one command is the equivalent of doing this:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus.git
cd micronucleus  # cd into the repo you just cloned
git checkout version_2.5
# To be pedantic, also delete the local `master` branch since
# technically it won't exist yet since you haven't yet checked
# it out with `git checkout master`, which would create it from
# your locally-stored remote-tracking branch, `origin/master`
git branch -d master
```

The `-b version_2.5` part automatically checked out the `version_2.5` branch for us instead of `master`.

`git branch -a` shows us that ALL branches, however, were cloned to our local PC. Here you can see our local branch `version_2.5`, which we are on, plus the locally-stored *remote-tracking branches* `origin/HEAD` (which points to `origin/master`), plus `origin/master`, and `origin/version_2.5`:

```bash
$ git branch -a
* version_2.5
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/version_2.5
```

We can also look at what our `fetch` references are. You can either open up the `.git/config` file to see them directly, or just run `git config remote.origin.fetch`:

```bash
$ git config remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can see above that our `git fetch` command (which is also triggered by `git pull` since that is equivalent to `git fetch && git merge`) is configured to fetch ALL heads for ALL branches in the `origin` remote. I'm not an expert on this part, but I believe that's what `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` means.

## Breakdown of the 1st command from above:

**The 1st command** (`git clone -b version_2.5 --single-branch https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus.git`) clones ONLY the `version_2.5` branch to your local PC, and it also checks it out. That one command is the equivalent of doing this (in the end result at least, except that it also downloads much less data in the beginning since it only clones ONE branch NOT all of them):

```bash
git clone https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus.git
cd micronucleus  # cd into the repo you just cloned
git checkout version_2.5

# Delete ALL other branches, including remote-tracking ones, which are not the 
# `version_2.5` branch:
# One local branch
git branch -d master
# ALL other locally-stored remote-tracking branches
git branch -dr origin/HEAD 
git branch -dr origin/master

# Fix your `.git/config` file so that `git fetch` does the right thing, fetching
# ONLY the `version_2.5` branch head from the `origin/version_2.5` remote branch:
git config remote.origin.fetch \
"+refs/heads/version_2.5:refs/remotes/origin/version_2.5"
```

The `-b version_2.5` part caused the `version_2.5` branch to be checked out instead of the `master` branch by default (as previously explained above), and the `--single-branch` part caused:

1. **NONE of the other branches to be cloned to our PC**, and
2. `git fetch` to be configured such that **NONE of the other branches will ever be fetched when we call `git fetch` or `git pull`!**

This command truly cloned and will fetch only the one branch we wanted, *and that's it!*

`git branch -a` shows us that ONLY the `version_2.5` branch was cloned and checked out. Here we see by the `*` which branch is checked-out, and we see also that we have a *locally-stored* remote-tracking branch for `origin/version_2.5`:

```bash
$ git branch -a
* version_2.5
  remotes/origin/version_2.5
```

We can also look at what our `fetch` references are. You can either open up the `.git/config` file to see them directly, or just run `git config remote.origin.fetch`:

```bash
$ git config remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/version_2.5:refs/remotes/origin/version_2.5
```

You can see above that our `git fetch` command will only fetch the `version_2.5` branch head from the `origin/version_2.5` remote branch. That's it! Beware that no other remote branches will ever be fetched.

## Summary:

So, now you see that using `-b branch_name` basically just ensures the `branch_name` branch is checked-out after the clone, but still clones ALL remote branches, whereas adding also `--single-branch` ensures that ONLY `branch_name` is cloned, fetched, pulled, and tracked. *No other remote branches will be cloned to your PC whatsoever.*

Personally, I prefer the `-b branch_name` option alone, because I want *all* branches cloned to my local PC. The one exception might be on a huge, shared mono-repo which has dozens, or even hundreds or thousands of remote branches. In that case, just use `-b branch_name --single-branch` to clone just the one main branch you care about and be done. Better to download 50 GiB of data for the `master` branch in a huge mono-repo, for instance, than to download 200 GiB of data so you can have 2000 of your peers' branches they are working on too!

## References:

1. [Clone only one branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811434/clone-only-one-branch/14930421#14930421)
2. [How do you stop tracking a remote branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046436/how-do-you-stop-tracking-a-remote-branch-in-git/3046478#3046478)

Answer (score 7):

```
git clone --branch <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
```

or

```
git clone -b <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
```

Answer (score 6):

I did it this way

git clone -b <branch_name> url

example :

```
git clone -b master https://gitlab.com/jhondoe/applicationproject.git
```

or

```
git clone -b master git@gitlab.com:jhondoe/applicationproject.git
```

Answer (score 6):

## ️ Some Performance Measurements ️

I compared two of the suggested approaches, and found that one is way faster (and smaller) than the other (which is advantageous if your only goal is to clone, and you don't care about much else).

I found that the most important performance indicator is `--depth`, meaning that [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/2228771) is the fastest.
Try it yourself:

```sh
time bash -cl "git clone --single-branch --depth=1 --branch=$MYBRANCH $MYGITURL"
```

I tested this with a big project with a long history and many branches, and this approach takes about 6s.

Note that, contrary to what is claimed by several comments in this thread, (at least in a recent git version), this will only `checkout` the target branch. `git branch -a` only lists that single branch.

### The Runner Up

By comparison, [frerich-rabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91757/frerich-raabe)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146786/2228771) consistently took 26s:

```sh
time bash -cl "git init && git remote add -t $MYBRANCH -f origin $MYGITURL && git checkout $MYBRANCH"
```

When comparing the two, it is also important to note that, in my case, the target branch is a much slimmed down version of its parent branch. The first approach's download progress bar reflects that reduction in size (< 10MB), while the second does not (> 90MB). (I'm sure, there are more mature methods to measure total download size, but I have not looked into that yet.)

Answer (score 5):

For cloning a specific branch you can do  :

```
git clone --branch yourBranchName git@yourRepository.git
```

Comment: what  does indicate git@yourRepository.git?

Answer (score 4):

For cloning a branch of Git you don't have the public key to, use this:

```
git clone -b <branch> <Git repository URL or clone URL you get from Git repository>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
git clone --single-branch -b [branch name]  [repository URL]
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the cmd.

```
cd folder_name  # enter the path where to clone the branch
```

Just one command:

```
git clone url_of_projecturltoclone -b branch_name
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late but I wanted to add the solution I used to solve this problem. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527999/how-do-i-create-a-new-github-repo-from-a-branch-in-an-existing-repo).

Anyway, the question seems to be asking 'how to start a new project from a branch of another repo?'

To this, the solution I used would be to first create a new repo in github or where ever. This will serve as the repo to your new project.

On your local machine, navigate to the project that has the branch you want to use as the template for your new project.

Run the command:

```
git push https://github.com/accountname/new-repo.git +old_branch:master
```

What this will do is push the old_branch to new-repo and make it the master branch of the new repo.

You then just have to clone the new repo down to your new project's local directory and you have a new project started at the old branch.

Answer (score 3):

Let us take the example of flask repo. It has 3 branches in addition to master. Let us checkout the 1.1.x remote branch

clone the git repo

```
git clone https://github.com/pallets/flask
```

cd into the repo.

```
cd flask
```

fetch remote branch 1.1.x

```
git fetch origin 1.1.x
```

checkout the branch

```
git checkout 1.1.x
```

You will switch to the branch 1.1.x and it will track the remote 1.1.x branch.

Answer (score 3):

There are primarily 2 solutions for this:

1. You need to specify the branch name with -b command switch. Here is the syntax of the command to clone the specific git branch.

   ```
   git clone -b <BRANCH_NAME> <GIT_REMOTE_URL>
   ```

   **Example:**

   ```
   git clone -b tahir https://github.com/Repository/Project.git
   ```

   The following command will clone the branch **tahir** from the git repository.The above command clones only the specific branch but fetches the details of other branches. You can view all branches details with command.

   ```
   git branch -a
   ```
2. You can use `--single-branch` flag to prevent fetching details of other branches like below:

   ```
   git clone -b <BRANCH_NAME> --single-branch <GIT_REMOTE_URL>
   ```

   **Example:**

   ```
   git clone -b tahir --single-branch \ 
   https://github.com/Repository/Project.git
   ```

   Now if you do a `git branch -a`, it will only show your current single branch that you have cloned and not all the branches. So it depends on you how you want it.

Comment: This isn't quite right. fetching **is** cloning! When you fetch a remote branch, you are cloning that remote branch's contents to your *locally-stored* `remote_name/branch_name` (ex: `origin/branch1`) local remote-tracking clone of that remote branch. So, when you say: "The above command [referring to `git clone -b tahir https://github.com/Repository/Project.git`] clones only the specific branch but fetches the details of other branches.", this is wrong. Actually, _it clones all the branches._ It just _checks out_ the `tahir` branch after cloning all the branches is all.

Comment: That means for your bullet 2, you should also change this ("You can use `--single-branch` flag to prevent fetching details of other branches like below:") to this instead: "You can use the `--single-branch` option to prevent cloning (fetching) all the other branches. Instead, it will just clone (fetch) and then checkout the one branch you specify. See the example below:...".

Answer (score 2):

If you want a shallow clone, you can do this with:

```
git clone -b mybranch --depth=1 https://example.com/myproject.git localname
```

`--depth=1` implies `--single-branch`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this command to git single branch and rename the folder if you want to keep branched stand alone

```
git clone -b [branch-name] --single-branch [url]  [folder_name]
```

example

```
git clone -b mybranch --single-branch git://github/repository.git  project_mybranch
```

Answer (score 2):

**This should work**

```
git clone --single-branch <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
git clone --branch <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Usign Github CLI

If you are cloning a repo using the [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com), clone options must be declared differently.

### --depth=1

```
gh repo clone username/repo -- --depth=1
```

### --single-branch

```
gh repo clone username/repo -- --single-branch
```

### --branch

```
gh repo clone username/repo -- --branch main --single-branch localDir
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @nosaiba-darwish said here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31848172/6192084)

This is what we usually do in our company:

```
git clone -b <name_of_branch> --single-branch <git_url> folder_to_clone_locally
```

Answer (score 1):

For the newbies like me,
just run the code below

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/repo/repo.git --branch <name of branch> --single-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone --branch {branch-name} {repo-URI}
```

**Example:**

```
git clone --branch dev https://github.com/ann/cleaningmachine.git
```

- dev: This is the `{branch-name}`
- https://github.com/ann/cleaningmachine.git: This is the `{repo-URI}`

Answer (score -4):

Can be done in 2 steps

1. Clone the repository

   ```
   git clone <http url>
   ```
2. Checkout the branch you want

   ```
   git checkout $BranchName
   ```

Comment: Actually, the `git clone <http url>` part clones **all** the branches to your local computer, NOT just the one branch you wanted cloned. This is because it fetches all branches to your local remote-tracking `remote_name/branch_name` branches, which are true, local clones of those branches. Do `git branch -a` to see all local and local remote-tracking (fetched) branches on your system for proof of this. Using the `--single-branch` option truly keeps those other branches off your system, however, and `git branch -a` will only show the one branch you wanted.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but this is the reason for your downvotes: people recognize your answer actually clones the entire repo not just the one branch, indicating you don't really know what's happening here, so they downvoted you.