# On a new machine, how do I fetch an existing branch?

Tags: git, repository, github

I'm not new to git, but I'm not a gitmaster.

I have an existing branch on my git account, that I would like to pull, but when I do this :

```
git checkout previously_created_branch
```

I get..

```
error: pathspec 'previously_created_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git must know from where you want to get the branch

First fetch the changes from your remote repository:

```
git fetch origin
```

Then you can check it out with

```
git checkout -t origin/previously_created_branch
```

This will create a local branch of the same name, that tracks the remote branch

Comment: it's git checkout -t origin/prev_created_branch

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout branch-name` is used to switch branches.

To pull, you should use: `git pull origin branch-name`, assuming that your remote is named `origin`.

Comment: Yah it didn't work. I get the error I wrote above. If I do git-pull, it says, everything-up-to-date , even though I know for a fact it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not tracking the remote branch on the new machine?

To see the list of remote branches:

```
git branch -r
```

To track the branch locally (if it isn't already):

```
git branch --track previously_created_branch origin/previously_created_branch
```