# Cloning only a specific branch on Github?

Tags: git, github, branch

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter for one of my github projects and would like to use the "Fork" feature to do it. However, I just need one branch (the stable one) for my repo. Cloning the whole CodeIgniter repository gives me about 30M of data, most of which I don't need.

How can I fork a specific branch of a repository from within Github (so I have the "forked from..." thing on my repo). Is this possible?

Comment: One way would be to fork, and then delete the parts you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only fork the whole repository on GitHub. However, you can [clone just a single branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git) from your fork to save time and space.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking to fork the repo but just a specific branch of it. Is the only way to do that to fork the whole thing and delete?

Comment: Yeah, but as the forking happens on GitHub alone, you usually don’t need to care about it, if you just want to clone a single branch then.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use `fork` feature.