# Git clone from CodeAurora.org, only a single repo, not the entire project

Tags: git, git-clone

So, I was wondering there is any way to to clone this repo:
https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=kernel/msm.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/korg/linux-3.0.y;hb=refs/heads/korg/linux-3.0.y without cloning the entire project like this:

```
git clone git://codeaurora.org/kernel/msm.git
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone a single branch in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Comment: I tried with git clone git://codeaurora.org/kernel/msm.git --branch korg/linux-3.0.y but it still clones the whole kernel.msm.git repo.

Comment: You forgot `--single-branch`.