# github newbie: clone doesn't seem to have gotten me the right files

Tags: git, github

I just tried to use git for the first time and got unexpected results.

I ran `git clone https://github.com/dato/lesswrong-bundle.git` which downloaded the following files to a directory called `lesswrong-bundle`

- _config.yml
- css
- index.md
- _layouts
- lesswrong-seq_paper.pdf
- lesswrong-seq.pdf

What I expected was [this list of files](https://github.com/dato/lesswrong-bundle) which is rather different. This page lists `https://github.com/dato/lesswrong-bundle.git` by the "Git Read-Only" button, which is the obvious argument to the `git` command.

There is a link to a zip file which contains the files I wanted, but what went wrong the first time?

Answer (score 3):

You just clone **gh-pages** branch

Here is the right command:

```
   git clone -b master https://github.com/dato/lesswrong-bundle.git
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git).

Answer (score 2):

I tried your command and I've your same issue. Then I switched to master tree with

```
git checkout master
```

And I've found your right files. As you can see, the files you've found before belong to the "gh-pages" branch. You have 2 branches in this repo 1) master (the one you needed) 2) gh-pages.