# Git: Clone from a branch other than master

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to pull from a repository in Github. But I don't want to clone the master branch. I want to clone some other branch. When I try `git clone <url>`, I get the files from the master branch. What should I do?

Also, suppose the code is updated in the repository and I want to get the latest code, should I again use `git clone` ? Because the size of the project is huge. Also if I make changes to the project locally, and then I again use git clone, will the changes I made still be there? What if I don't want changes to be there?

I am not even sure if `git clone` is the right command. `git pull` or `git fetch`?

I am sorry, I am very new to git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try this:

```
git init
git fetch url-to-repo branchname:refs/remotes/origin/branchname
```

**EDIT**

A better solution:

```
git clone -b mybranch --single-branch git://sub.domain.com/repo.git
```

Comment: I did not get the part after url-to-repo. Should I just mention the branchname? For example- git fetch <url> demo (assuming dev is the branch name?)

Comment: I've changed for a cleaner solution

Comment: BTW for the first solution: where it says "branchname" it should said the branch that you want to clone something like  `git fetch my_repo_url demo:refs/remotes/origin/demo`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I tried `git branch -l` and got all the branches. I am trying the second solution.

Comment: what does '--single-branch' do?

Comment: Sweet! This saved me a ton of time. I had trouble with another clone on my machine. I brought a branch from that clone into my new clone. Et voila!

Comment: @ user3804598                                                                                                     
           type this       git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]                                                                --single-branch       clone only one branch, HEAD or --branch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git

Answer (score 41):

```
git clone <url>
```

clones and creates remote-tracking branches for each branch.
If you want to see available branches (after cloning), you type

```
git branch -l
```

To switch to a particular branch after cloning you do:

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

where branchname is the name of the branch :)

If you want to clone and checkout a specific branch you do

```
git clone -b <branchname> <url>
```

The other commands you mention are for "updating" your current working copy. `git pull` gets all changes from the remote repository and merges them while `git fetch`only gets them without merging.

Comment: Actually I think it is `git clone -b <branchname> <url>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But I can choose only one answer as the correct answer. I can't upvote your answer also because it requires at least 15 reputation points.

Comment: Luckily having the order as `git clone <url> -b <branchname>` also works. This is good for requirements files. Where you might have `while read; do git clone $REPLY; done < requirements.txt` in a build script. Most entries in that file would just be URLs, but you can also add `-b <branchname>` to the end of any of them.

Comment: git clone -b <branchname> <url>, this solved my problem.

Comment: I've never seen nor used `git branch -l` in my entire life before! I checked the man pages. It turns out that is the default whenever you call just `git branch`, which is what I've been doing my whole life. That `-l` really threw me off. From `man git branch`: `If --list is given, or if there are no non-option arguments, existing branches are listed`.

Comment: Also, I think you mean to say to use `git branch -a`, *not* `git branch -l`. The `-a` option shows all branches, including the remote-tracking ones, whereas the `-l` option (or the lack of any options: just `git branch`) will not show remote-tracking branches at all, so you wouldn't be able to see what branches exist on github but not locally unless you use `git branch -r` to show remote branches, or `git branch -a` to show all branches.

Answer (score 5):

use `git clone --branch <name>` possibly adding `--single-branch`

as usual you have `git clone --help` to read details on commands

Answer (score 4):

If you already cloned the repo and want to **contribute to the branch other than master**, do this:

```
$ git checkout --track origin/<branch-name>
```

---

*Of course, be sure to specify the right name of the remote (origin in the example above)*

This command will create a new local branch that will track a particular remote branch.

Comment: What is the behavior if the local branch name already exists?  Does it throw an error?  Or does it just elegantly switch to that branch?