# Git clone repo into a new folder

Tags: git, repository, git-clone

So here is the issue or more like confusion I have.

Currently I have a git repo (lets just say the name is rn) that is connected to a folder called assg_rad. In this folder,   I have some error that I have no idea how to solve it, so I want to git clone rn into a new folder and continue my work from there.

1. Is this possible?
2. Will this affect the old assg_rad folder as this folder is previously where the git remote is?
3. Will there be confusion between two folders because they will have same repo?
4. How to do this git clone? Is it the same like when you clone a new repo, or is there a different steps?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, No, No, Yes. Just go to different folder directory where you want to start working and use the git clone command there.

Comment: What if I git clone from the branches instead of master? Will I lose all of the branches I already made in the old repo or is there a way to solve this?

Comment: there wont be any clash of code or branches between the new folder you are creating and old folder. You can  clone into a new folder using ``` git clone <gitrepo> <foldername>``` this command creates the folder if its not present.

Comment: I have another question. So I clone from this branch that is not a master branch. For example, the name is "database". If I clone from this branch, does "database" branch automatically become the new master branch or can I still make it as branches from master?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383217/clone-from-a-branch-other-than-master

Can this work but only without --singlebranch because I want all my branches to appear?