# How to remove all commits of a topic Git branch?

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, git-branch-sculpting

Suppose I have the following history:

```
   A---B---C----------D------------E master
            \         /\         /
            W1--X1--Y1 W2--X2--Y2 
                  topic1      topic2
```

Is it possible to  remove all topic branches and their commits as following

`A-B-C-D-E master`

Comment: I assume D and E are merge commits? Do you want to keep the changes done by W1-Y2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options for doing this.

### Solution 1: Squash Merges

One solution is to simply use a hard reset with a few squash merges:

```bash
git checkout master
git reset --hard C

git merge --squash topic1
git commit -m "Rewrite D"

git merge --squash topic2
git commit -m "Rewrite E"

# Verify that the new branch is no different from the old one
git diff sha_of_old_E
```

The idea here is that a squash merge will copy the **final state** of a topic branch (i.e. the last commit) into your current working copy, where you can then commit it. It effectively squashes a branch into a single commit.

#### Documentation

- [git-merge(1) Manual Page](http://jk.gs/git-merge.html).

### Solution 2: Interactive Rebase

Another method is to use an interactive rebase to squash the topic branches into a single commit. First, invoke the rebase

```
git rebase -i C
```

That will bring up the interactive rebase TODO list editor in your terminal. You'll see the following commits displayed:

```
pick sha W1
pick sha X1
pick sha Y1
pick sha W2
pick sha X2
pick sha Y2
```

What you want to do is something similar to the squash merge above. You can to squash the topic branches into single commits, so for each commit of a topic branch, squash (or "fixup") the descendant commit into its parent:

```
pick sha W1
squash sha X1
squash sha Y1
pick sha W2
squash sha X2
squash sha Y2
```

Then hit `:wq` in the Vim editor to begin the interactive rebase. I won't go into detail about the next steps, because they're already adequately detailed in other numerous sources around the internet, such as in [Pro Git § 6.4 Git Tools - Rewriting History - Squashing Commits](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits).

You'll probably want to double check that you did the rebase correctly by verifying that the newly rewritten branch is no different from the previous one by using a simple diff:

```
git diff sha_of_old_E
```

Note that if you'd rather not bother editing the commit messages for each squash, you can use "fixup" instead, which will just reuse the commit message of the previous commit:

```
pick sha W1
fixup sha X1
fixup sha Y1
pick sha W2
fixup sha X2
fixup sha Y2
```

Note that you can also use `s` or `f` for squash and fixup, respectively.

#### Documentation

- [git-merge(1) Manual Page](http://jk.gs/git-merge.html).
- [git-rebase(1) Manual Page](http://jk.gs/git-rebase.html).
- [Pro Git § 6.4 Git Tools - Rewriting History - Squashing Commits](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Squashing-Commits).

### Warning about force pushing

Note that both of the above solutions will rewrite your commit history, of course, so your new commits will have different sha IDs. If you've already pushed the old version of your branch to your remote, then you'll need to force push to overwrite the old copy. This may not be something you want to do if you're sharing your branch with other people, for reasons which I won't detail here, since the possible dangers of force pushing are well documented in numerous other online sources, such as:

- [Pro Git § 3.6 Git Branching - Rebasing - The Perils of Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing)

Answer (score 2):

One trick would be to [clone a single branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309) from that repo into a new repo

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch [<folder>]
```

And use the new repo from there.

Answer (score -1):

You could use interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i <hash of A>
```

and then delete the commits you don't want by just deleting the lines referring to the commits. You will have something like:

```
pick <hash of B> message of B
pick <hash of C> message of C
pick <hash of W1> message of W1
pick <hash of X1> message of X1
pick <hash of Y1> message of Y1
pick <hash of D> message of D
pick <hash of W2> message of W2
pick <hash of X2> message of X2
pick <hash of Y2> message of Y2
pick <hash of E> message of E
```

Then delete those lines referring to the topic branches like this:

```
pick <hash of B> message of B
pick <hash of C> message of C
pick <hash of D> message of D
pick <hash of E> message of E
```

Comment: Didn't downvote, but note that the merge commits D and E won't actually show up with the interactive rebase command that you used. Not only that, but removing commits from the interactive rebase editor typically means that you're **throwing away the changes** from those commits, so that they won't be preserved in any of the descendants. Surely that's not what you or the question asker really want, is it? Have you actually tried running your above commands yourself, to see what would happen?

Comment: @Cupcake With the phrase `remove all topic branches and their commits` I understood that he wanted to throw away those changes, and in the question there was not written that D and E was merge commits, but yeah maybe I should assumed that. I'm sorry if I misunderstood the issue, didn't mean to damage the answerer.

Comment: You can see in the commit graph that the asker gave that D and E are merge commits.