# Critical situation in removing a local branch

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-remote

I'm using the following command to remove a local branch with **force delete** option:

```
$ git branch -D <branch_name>
```

My question is, If I delete a **local branch** that had an **upstream** set and then do a normal push, it won't delete the **remote branch** right?

What should I do in this situation?

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `"-D"` is force delete option.
- I want to delete the local branch and keep the remote branch on origin.

---

Comment: Yes, you'd have to explicitly `push --delete` or `push :<branch_name>` to remove it remotely.

Comment: @miqid I want delete a local branch only, not actual remote branch on origin.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

git will only delete your local branch, please keep in mind that local and remote branches actually have nothing to do with each other. They are completely separate objects in Git.

Even if you've established a tracking connection (which you should for most scenarios), this still does not mean that deleting one would delete the other, too!

If you want any branch item to be deleted, you need to delete it explicitly.

**Deleting local branches in Git**

```
git branch -d <branch_name>
```

using a capital `-D` is like a "force" version of `-d`. If the branch isn't fully merged you'll get an error if you use the lowercase version. This again has no relevance to the remote branches and will only delete your local branch.

**Deleting remote branches in Git**

```
git push origin --delete <branch_name>
```

so to your question

> If I delete a local branch that had an upstream set and then do a
>   normal push, it won't delete the remote branch right?

You are correct it will not delete the remote branch.

Comment: I used capital `D` in my question.

Comment: edited my question to supply you the answer you need @BenyaminJafari

Comment: but in comments in below of my question, @miqid said "yes"!

Comment: its a different command to delete a remote branch.. what you are doing is correct and will not affect any remote branches.