# Download a specific branch of a github project

Tags: git, github, nolearn

To cut the story short, to run a convolutional neural network model, I need an special version of `nolearn`, which has a url of the form https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/tree/1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4/nolearn . However, there are no `Download as Zip` buttons at the page, nor I can download it with

```
git clone https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn -branch 1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4/nolearn
```

Simply,

```
git clone https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/tree/1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4/nolearn
```

does not work, too.

Even, I have no idea what should I search for in Google!

Note: This is the last version which provided support for the class `Objective`, i.e. the command `from lasagne.objectives import Objective` is no more supported!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Other than in Subversion (SVN), git has separate namespaces for directories (file system folders), branches and tags. Thus https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/tree/1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4/nolearn is not, per se, a branch. `1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4` is a commit ID, used here to refer to the revision created by the commit. `dnouri/nolearn` is the repository name on GitHub (repository `nolearn` on account `dnouri`) and the final `nolearn` in the URL is a directory within the content of revision `1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4`.

The 'normal' way to get this code with git would be:

1. replicate the repository to your local machine

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn.git
   ```

   (You can find this URL on the repository's page https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn, in the 'clone URL' field.)
2. enter the local repository

   ```
   cd nolearn
   ```
3. check out the wanted revision

   ```
   git checkout 1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4
   ```
4. change into the respective directory inside the repository

   ```
   cd nolearn
   ```

Comment: it's less data consuming by using @mayo's answer: ```git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch <folder>```

Comment: That's true @RicoNeitzel, but AFAIK it's not what Git users would usually do, unless the amount of data really is a problem. (And if so, one should probably consider whether all that data really belongs into a single Git repo.)

Answer (score 45):

This can help you:

[How to clone a single branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Where specifies:

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch [<folder>]
```

Docu :

[Git Clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

> --[no-]single-branch
>
> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the --branch option or the primary
>   branch remote’s HEAD points at. When creating a shallow clone with the
>   --depth option, this is the default, unless --no-single-branch is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches. Further
>   fetches into the resulting repository will only update the
>   remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the
>   initial cloning. If the HEAD at the remote did not point at any branch
>   when --single-branch clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is
>   created.

Comment: Note to other noobs like me, the `folder` name in the command above should not be inside square brackets.

Comment: Good point! I am not sure but it seems like a convention from i-dont-know-where that square brackets mean an optional parameter.

Answer (score 5):

This is the link to the .zip : https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/archive/1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4.zip

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, this is not the one I need! This is the latest version on `master` branch, not the one I need.

Comment: That should work, I've inserted the right link:https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/archive/1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4.zip

Comment: Thanks. It just worked. However, I wonder if there are any `git` hacks around?

Comment: Git hacks? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean some switches in the command line, e.g. `git clone https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn --some-magic-switch 1659e4811e498dc1f442d8e6486d0831f85255b4`

Comment: @Das-g mentioned the 'magic switch' you're looking for and the reason you couldn't download it.

Comment: Thanks! For everyone that uses Github and not the git CLI, I've found that the URL `https://github.com/<username>/<repository>/archive/<branch>.zip` will download that branch.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for zip that would work for any repo and branch:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repository>/archive/<branch>.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download a snapshot of any branch, tag, or specific commit from GitHub.com. Source code archives are available at specific URLs for each repository. For example, consider the repository `github/codeql` There are different URLs for downloading a branch, a tag, or a specific commit ID.

Branch - main - https://github.com/github/codeql/archive/refs/heads/main.tar.gz

Tag - codeql-cli/v2.12.0 -  https://github.com/github/codeql/archive/refs/tags/codeql-cli/v2.12.0.zip

Commit - aef66c4 -https://github.com/github/codeql/archive/aef66c462abe817e33aad91d97aa782a1e2ad2c7.zip

Patch - https://github.com/repo/codeql/pull/pull-id.patch

You can use either `.zip` or `.tar.gz` in the URLs above to request a zipball or tarball respectively.