# How to clone a github sub branch with HTTPS?

Tags: git, github

This is what I have:

I have a main branch ABC and two subbranches DEF and GHI. These two subbranches are used by two different people, Obviously.

I don't have a git client. I'm using a software called as [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_(software)) using which I can download code from a git repository.

I have URL for the main branch. 
https://github.com/abc/abc-app.git

But I don't have URL for a subbranch, I'm trying to obtain such a URL for one of those subbranches so that I can integrate it in Jenkins.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Cloning in git clones the whole repository, including ALL the branches. Use `git checkout <branch>` to get the right branch after that, or in case of jenkins, see the section called *Branches to build* under Source code management - Git

Comment: I know that. But if, a sub branch URL was available, it would have been perfect. I was trying to get that.

Answer (score 0):

> But if, a sub branch URL was available, it would have been perfect

There is not, but in a way, [you can clone a single branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309):

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch [<folder>]
```

It is not an url, but it still allow you to get only the branch you want.