# Difference between downloaded Odoo 8.0 from a normal Download to a Git Clone Odoo 8

Tags: git, odoo, odoo-8

I have a problem in downloading the Odoo in Git due to my intermittent internet connection.
I just want to copy My Odoo 8 the Manual Downloaded Ones to the `opt` directory but the DL is only 430MB but in git the file to be downloaded will be 1GB?

Is there any difference to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Odoo 8 is a branch in the Odoo repo (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/8.0), you can try and [limit your clone to that only branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309):

```
git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch [<folder>]
git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo--branch 8.0 --single-branch -- odoo8
```

You can add `--depth 1` if you don't want the full history, which further reduce the volume of data to download.

The difference (when cloning a repo Git) in downloaded size comes from the branches and their full history.

Comment: Thanks sir right I've downloaded it using git with only --depth 1, and maybe in my other installation i will add the --single-branch. Thanks a Lot again