# clone only a specific branch to bare repo

Tags: git, git-bare

I want to clone only a specific branch of a non bare repo to create a bare repo. So basically, from the git repo, I will do a `git clone repo.git` which will clone the existing repo and create a new folder repo.git. On doing a `git branch` in the new repo, it has the same branch as the old repo had (say master). Is there a way I can specify the branch while cloning so that the bare repo has that branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone a single branch in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Comment: you want to clone an existing branch, but keep it empty? you plan on committing future code to the same repo you cloned from?

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` will clone the HEAD set in remote repository (usually it is set to `master` branch) to local.

you can run `git clone repo.git -b xxxx` to specify which branch to clone to your local.

Comment: git clone --bare <repo_url.git> -b <branch-name>

Comment: This cloned all of the branches.