# Cloning a remote branch - why does git think it doesn't exist?

Tags: git

I can list the branches on my remote repository like this

```
git ls-remote https://blah.visualstudio.com/Blah/_git/Software
```

which gives me the list of branches available on the remote:

> e7dcd105d5a03d0dc176f9e29fae020c0419c4fb   HEAD
>   500fde10ba1498fe5c0118b095fe21521ea4e569   refs/heads/Task/150-Xamarin

(N.B. I've snipped most of them out.)

Following the documentation for [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone.html) I should (I think) be able to clone the remote repository but only taking the tip of one branch. Here are the versions of the command that I have tried

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch Task/150-Xamarin -- https://blah.visualstudio.com/Blah/_git/Software  
git clone --depth 1 --branch heads/Task/150-Xamarin -- https://blah.visualstudio.com/Blah/_git/Software  
git clone --depth 1 --branch refs/heads/Task/150-Xamarin -- https://blah.visualstudio.com/Blah/_git/Software
```

Every one of these return variations of the error

> Cloning into 'Software'...
>   warning: Could not find remote branch Task/150-Xamarin -- to clone.
>   fatal: Remote branch Task/150-Xamarin -- not found in upstream origin

If I omit the `--` I get a different error. For example from

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch Task/150-Xamarin https://blah.visualstudio.com/Blah/_git/Software
```

I get the error

> You must specify a repository to clone.

I don't understand. The remote branch is listed by `git ls-remote` why can't I get it in the shallow clone?

Comment: Remove `--`. It's incorrect use.

Comment: Thanks ElpieKay. You are correct, though that did not fix it for me. It certainly helped me diagnose the true cause of my problem which was that the branch name ended with a non-breaking space character which git read as part of the branch name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My original answer worked, but is misleading. ElpieKay's comment on the question led me to dig further. My problem was not the ordering of the arguments to `git clone`. In fact this command works fine

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch Task/150-Xamarin https://blah.visualstudio.com/Blah/_git/Software
```

That looks absolutely identical to the failing command in my question. I only spotted the difference when I looked at them in a binary editor. Here's the fragment "Xamarin https" from the two commands. The one that succeeds is

> 0x58 0x61 0x6D 0x61 0x72 0x69 0x6E 0x20 0x68 0x74 0x74 0x70 0x73

While the one that fails looks like this

> 0x58 0x61 0x6D 0x61 0x72 0x69 0x6E 0xC2 0xA0 0x68 0x74 0x74 0x70 0x73

That's the problem. The branch name in the failing commands is not followed by a normal whitespace character (encoded in UTF8 as 0x20) but by a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (encoded in UTF8 as 0xC2 0xA0). Git was including the trailing non-breaking space as part of the branch name and thus failing to find it on the remote.

I have no idea how a non-breaking space made it into my git command, but that was my problem.

---

For completeness, here is my original answer.

*The order of the arguments in the documentation for [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone.html) is misleading. This is the command that successfully colnes the tip of just one branch*

```
git clone https://blah.visualstudio.com/Blah/_git/Software --depth 1 --branch Task/150-Xamarin
```

*(via [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/575530) to the question "How to clone a single branch in git?")*

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that

```
git ls-remote --heads origin
```

returned something like

```
46d0adaf08ef87d0aa840f9a4338d172bf931752    refs/heads/pilot/buildsplit
349502cbb72664c376b2392bdbe8179725a52012    refs/heads/testing/time
32670bd5f6014542d8f9f3854e5aebff5eb8dddf    refs/heads/testing/health
```

And if I want to clone e.g. the branch `time`, I need to **discard** the `refs/heads/` **part** and use

```
git clone --single-branch -b testing/time https://git.LINK_TO_REPO.git
```

Note that simply using commit hash instead of name doesn't work.