# Git denies the existence of remote branches

Tags: git

I have a git repo checked out from github, but it refuses to acknowledge any remote branches.

Here's what I've tried (names changed to protect the guilty):

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
$ git fetch
$ git remote update
Fetching origin
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
$ git remote show
origin
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:Someplace/someproject.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:Someplace/someproject.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:Someplace/someproject.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Someplace/someproject.git (push)
```

On another machine, it just works:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/somebranch
  ...
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of you .git/config file?  In particular, the `[remote "origin"]` section?  I wonder if your fetch line is different than usual for some reason.  It should generally be something like `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Comment: They may have been removed by accident.  What does a fresh clone say about remotes?  What does github itself think?

Comment: Fresh clone still doesn't work. The git config has this: `fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: @Karl your fetch-string tells only to fetch `master`, please change it to line with `*` as in  jszakmeister's example.

Comment: So am I going to have to manually edit the config file every time I fetch a new repo?

Comment: What are you using for your `git clone` command?  Are you passing `--single-branch`?  Can you include the output of `git config -l` in your question too?  Perhaps you have a config setting that's affecting you (though I can't think of what that would be off-hand)

Comment: Oh, and someone else said it, but it's worth repeating.  You're fetch line says to only update master, which is why you are seeing the other branches.  Replacing `master` with `*` would fix your issue, but if new clones are doing this to you, we should figure out why.

Comment: Yes that was my point. It was a brand new clone that was doing this. And I wasn't using single-branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can confirm the existence of remote branches with [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

```
cd /patH/to/my/repo
git ls-remote
```

Or, from any directory:

```
git ls-remote git@github.com:Someplace/someproject.git
```

Second, make sure your local repo is set to fetch *all* branches with [the right refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#CRTB):

```
git config remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

(as suggested by [kan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438742/kan))

> am I going to have to manually edit the config file every time I fetch a new repo?

No because `refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` is the default refspec used by any `git clone`.
Unless, as [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentions, you use `git clone --single-branch`, which is [possible since  Git 1.7.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309).

Comment: It's worth noting here that a `--single-branch` clone changes the default refspec. It seems likely that Karl is using `git clone --single-branch` instead of plain `git clone`.

Comment: @torek it is worth noting indeed. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'll mention that this WAS a plain `git clone` (no command line switches) that set the refspec wrong, and still does it every time.

Comment: Also, when the refspec is wrong, even `git ls-remote` won't show anything.