# git fetch not fetching remote branches - how to fetch all remotes

Tags: git, github

What would be a reason for `git fetch` got fetching remote branches?

[How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

All I do is run `git fetch` - I then see

> C:\site\blog>git fetch
>   *master

I expect to see something like:

> C:\site\blog>git fetch
>   *master origin/branch1 origin/branch2

[git fetch doesn't fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/git-fetch-doesnt-fetch-all-branches)

I run the command in the accepted answer

`git config --get remote.origin.fetch`

The output of the command is

`+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

From what I understand this indicates that I'm not only tracking master but all remotes.

What's wrong? How do I fix this? What would be a reason you can't `git fetch`? Why is it broken?

running `git fetch -a` doesn't do anything either.

running `git branch -avv` gives me the following:

[image]

So why does `git fetch` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379081/track-all-remote-git-branches-as-local-branches)

```
for i in `git branch -a | grep remote | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; do git branch --track ${i#remotes/origin/} $i; done
```

It's wrong terminology. It's tracking remote branches as local.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mentioned in the comments of my own answer. i have edited it to reflect that comment.

Answer (score 2):

Check first if those branches were not *already* fetched:

```
git branch -avv
```

If there are no new commits on those branches, a `git fetch` would not fetch anything.

Check also if those branches are indeed there on the remote repo side (the one referenced by `origin`, in `git remote -v`)

To make sure you see *all* remote branches, you can declare them as local ones, as [I do here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309).

Comment: ok...so how do I fetch those remotes into local? `git fetch --all` doesn't work

Comment: @kawnah By checking first if there is anything to actually fetch: check on your remote repo if those branches are there.

Comment: There are remote branches to fetch, yes. So howcome fetch doesn't work?

Comment: @kawnah From your output, git fetch has worked. You can make those remote trakcing branches local if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/q/379081/6309

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this can count as a full answer, but thats what I use in a day-to-day job:

```
git fetch --all
```

to fetch all branches

Its written in [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

In order to see which branches are local and which have a "remote counterpart", I use

```
git branch -vv
```

If the branch description (one line per branch has something like [origin/....] it has a remote branch as well, otherwise it's only a local branch)

If I want to see what remote repositories are configured at all (say in a new project that already cloned from somewhere but I don't remember from where) I check that both fetch and push repos are set up:

```
git remote -v
```

Comment: No, git fetch --all does not fetch all branches: what the documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch---all) actually says it that it fetches from all remotes. The refspec (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42728970/6309) associated to those remotes remains key in order to known which branches are fetched. The rest is already in my answer.