# After cloning, do I have only one branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-clone

I am trying to understand my following situation:

There is a project in Github that me and other people are using. I believe it has several branches besides master (in particular "develop")

So I cloned the project to my computer with `git clone <url>`
and I got the project. I have been told that I should work with the develop branch *not* with the master branch

So I type `git branch` to see what branches are there and I got

```
$ git branch
* master
```

What? where is the develop branch?

Nevertheless I do `git checkout develop` and behold! I am now in the develop branch! I do `git branch` again and I could see

```
$ git checkout develop
Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'develop'
$ git branch
* develop
  master
```

what dark magic is happening here?? It says that develop was set to track the develop from origin! So before that develop was hidden? unreachable?

After doing `git log --oneline --decorate` I could see the origin/develop branch but what just happened here??

Comment: `git clone` creates remote-tracking branches for each branch repository.

Comment: Yes, and if you want just to clone one single branch, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-to-clone-a-single-branch-in-git) SO answer.

Comment: @Maroun so I have to use `git branch -a` to see everything and checkout to the one I want to work with?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Yes.

Comment: @KansaiRobot When you do `git branch -a`, remotes will be prefixed with `remotes/origin` or maybe `remotes/<somethingElse>` if your remote happens not be named `origin` (it's only a convention after all, even if very commonly used). Don't `git checkout remotes/origin/myBranch` but rather `git checkout myBranch` if you want to create a local version tracking the remote one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Comment: @phd Nope, I am not asking that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes, you have only one branch after `git clone`

In fact, just before `git clone` finishes, you have *no* branches.

#### But "having a branch" does not mean that much

Git uses *branch names* to remember specific commits.  Each name remembers *one*, and only one, commit.  Each commit is uniquely identified by its hash ID: a big ugly number like `b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f`.

It's the commits themselves that remember previous commits (by *their* big ugly hash IDs).  Git calls this the *parent* commit of each commit.  This means that a name like `master` is needed only to remember the *last* commit of any given branch.  Git calls this final commit the *tip* of the branch.

It also means that we can use a different, not-quite-a-branch, name to remember some *other* Git's branches!

#### Enter the remote-tracking branch

Making a clone involves, internally, running `git fetch`.  It's `git fetch` that copies the commits from some other Git, and `git fetch` also copies their *names*.  Their names are in fact branch names: these remember *their* branch tips, like `master` and `develop`.  But they're not *your* branch tip commits—not yet!  *Your* Git *renames* these, to `origin/master` and `origin/develop`.  Your Git's *remote-tracking names*, with the `origin` prefixes, remember their names *and* their tip commits.

Running `git fetch` updates your remote-tracking names, so that you know what their new branch tip commits are.  Of course, it also first gets any commits they have, that you don't.

#### The dark magic

> [`develop` suddenly appears:] what dark magic is happening here?

When you run `git checkout name`, Git starts by searching through your list of branch names for *`name`*.  If it exists, Git tries to check out the specific commit that is the tip of *your* branch *`name`*, and make that your current branch.  So far so good—but what if the name *doesn't* exist yet?

In this case, instead of just failing, `git checkout` searches through your *remote-tracking names*, like `origin/master` and `origin/develop`.  If there's exactly one that resembles the name you asked for, your Git now *creates* your own branch name, setting it to remember, as *your* branch tip commit, the same hash ID that your Git is remembering as *their* tip, using that remote-tracking name.

So now you have a `develop` and now Git can check it out!

In fact, this was the very last step of `git clone`: it's how you got your `master` in the first place.  After copying commits from `origin`, and changing their names to `origin/*`, your Git ran `git checkout master`.  Your `master` did not exist yet, so your Git created it from your `origin/master` that your Git created from their `master`.  (Whew!  It seems like the long way around, and it is, but it does all make sense eventually!)

Comment: @KansaiRobot, please read [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) and [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) to get the full grasp on the topic. I'd say reading the whole book it recommended. But especially importand is understanding that _all Git repositories are completely **free-standing** and independent,_ and all "linkage" between the branches in any repository with the branches in any other repository is completely a policy thing.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**

When you `clone` (then later when you `fetch`), your local version of the repo gets the updated definitions of remote branches but local counterparts are not created automatically. If you just checkout a (yet non existing locally) branch whose name matches one of the remote ones, git assumes for you that you need to track the remote version of the same.

Try `git branch -a` to see everything.

**For more**, see torek's very complete answer to unpack the details behind it.