# Maven SCM Git - Is it possible to check out just one branch? (--single-branch)

Tags: git, maven, maven-scm

I'm using Maven SCM to checkout a Git repository. I only need to clone one branch so I would like to add '--single-branch' to the clone command.

The documentation doesn't mention anything about using custom options so I assume it isn't straightforward but maybe there is a workaround.

Is this possible?

Comment: What I need is the behavior of `--single-branch` on Maven SCM Git. [It's absolutely possible to only clone one branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/927493).

Answer (score 1):

My [old answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309) mentioning the [`single-branch` option of `git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---no-single-branch) is *not* a duplicate of this question, which seeks to replicate that feature with the [Maven SCM plugin](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/).

[Commit d327618](https://github.com/apache/maven-scm/commit/d3276183d475b7d6dc32c58b5ffd94e98c09f1d2) seems to indicate this is already the case:

> ### clone only required branch

```
Git.cloneRepository().setURI( repository.getFetchUrl() ).setCredentialsProvider(
                              credentials ).setCloneAllBranches(true).setDirectory(
                              credentials ).setBranch( branch ).setDirectory(
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It still downloads all refs from the remote repository. I tried different SCM Git providers like JGit and by default there is no configuration that behaves like --single-branch.

Comment: @Hatchet Agreed. Maven Git SCM uses JGit anyway.

Comment: @Hatchet And the Maven GIt SCM codebase does not include "setBranchesToClone", which is what you would need to clone only one branch: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1065371/, and even that would not not well: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1085178/. Still: https://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/