# Can I clone a single git branch in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, clone

I have a TFS git repository which takes a long time to clone. Is there a way to only clone a single branch in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Git CLI, you should use (in a CMD or PowerShell instance or any other terminal-like client of your preference):

`git clone -b branch_name --single-branch 'repo_url'`

- `branch_name`: is the name of your branch.
- `repo_url` is the link of your remote repository.

This will import a specific branch from your remote repository.

According to this, you need to know that Visual Studio just read your .git (and other Git dependencies such as gitignore, gitmodules, etc) configuration.

### Considerations:

This works only with git 1.7.10 version and above.

### References:

- [Visual Studio 2017 Branching MSDN documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kenakamu/2017/09/30/git-and-visual-studio-2017-part-4/)
- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)