# How to clone a specific branch in Python, Colab?

Tags: python, git, github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I usually use this to clone a github repo in colab

!git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git

But say I want to clone a specific branch of the repo. I tried

!git clone https://github.com/user/repo/tree/branch.git

But I get an error

fatal: repository 'https://github.com/user/repo/tree/branch.git/' not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clone a single branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
!git clone -b branch_name https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

replace branch_name with the name of branch you want to clone