# What difference does adding "--single-branch" make in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I've cloned a single branch of a repo before using `git clone -b <branch-name> <repo-name>`, but recently saw `git clone --single-branch -b <branch-name> <repo-name>` being used.

What's the difference?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Answer (score 1):

The command you've used (`git clone -b <branch-name> <repo-name>`) clones the entire repo.  The only thing the `-b` option does here is change what's initially checked out.

`--single-branch` updates the default refspec so that *only* the specified branch's history (and related data) is downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on Mark Adelsberger's answer (which I've already upvoted): note that `git clone` means, in effect:

1. Make a new totally-empty directory, or if directed, take over an existing totally-empty directory:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/git/git
   ```

   will make new directory `git` to hold the new Git repository.  Enter this directory for the rest of these steps; but your command-line interpreter is not in the new directory, so after the clone finishes, you'll have to enter the new directory yourself.
2. Run `git init` in this empty directory, so that it now has a `.git` sub-directory to hold a Git repository.  The new Git repository is totally empty (no commits, no branches, etc., although you're on the non-existent `master` branch).
3. Run `git remote add origin url`.  For instance, for the above, Git would add a remote named `origin` that tells Git to connect to `https://github.com/git/git`.
4. Run any extra various `git config` commands needed as well.
5. Run `git fetch origin`.
6. Run `git checkout branch` for some named *`branch`*.

You can run these six steps manually, if you prefer, but `git clone` is easier.

Now that you know what the six steps are, it's easy to explain both the `-b` argument *and* the `--single-branch` argument:

- `-b branch` selects the argument to pass to `git checkout` in step 6.  If you don't pick a branch name yourself, your Git will get a recommendation from *their* Git, during step 5, and will use that name.
- `--single-branch` adds a `git config` command to step 4.  In particular, it changes the `remote.origin.fetch` setting.

The `git remote add` step would / will set `remote.origin.fetch` to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, which is an instruction to the `git fetch` command—see step 5—to fetch *all* branches and rename all of them to your `origin/*` remote-tracking names.

With `--single-branch`, `git clone` overrides the default.  Instead of `+refs/heads/*`, the left side of this refspec pair is `+refs/heads/branch`.  The right side is therefore `+refs/remotes/origin/branch`, so that your final `remote.origin.fetch` setting reads:

```
+refs/heads/<branch>:refs/remotes/origin/<branch>
```

which directs the `git fetch` in step 5, *and all future `git fetch` operations*, to update *only* your `origin/branch` remote-tracking name.

Note that if you don't specifically select some branch in advance, `git clone` will use whatever branch the other Git recommends in step 5, to achieve the step-4 configuration result.  This means that in fact these steps aren't quite in order: `git clone` just does each part internally wherever it's most convenient.  If you want, for some reason, to do this manually, you'll need to do the six steps in this order.  (You can use `git remote add` with the `-t` option to combine steps 3 and 4, though, as long as you don't need any other special configuration options due to other `git clone` options.)