# How to clone specific branch from GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

How to clone the specific branch from GitLab repository.

Comment: That the specific remote is hosted on GitLab is irrelevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a single branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Answer (score -1):

```
git clone -b <branch-name> <remote_repository>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).