# git fetch origin --all option to fetch all remote branch?

Tags: git, github

I cloned a repo, I was defaulted to a `master` branch. I have to do 'git fetch origin staging' to change to `staging` branch. But in the github there are bunch of feature branch like `f1, f2..` how to do git fetch origin all to get all of them instead fetch them one by one from the origin?

Comment: Did you clone with `--depth` or `--single-branch`?

Comment: nope what's that for? so there's no option to fetch all branches?

Comment: The `--depth` option implies the `--single-branch` option, and the `--single-branch` option directs `git clone` to alter the default setup that copies all commits, and turns all branch names into remote-tracking names. Based on your question, I was guessing that you had done this and therefore had only one remote-tracking name, but if not, I guess instead that you think `git clone` should copy all branches. In fact, it copies *no* branch names: instead, it runs one final Git command that creates one *new* branch. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64840425/1256452) for details.

Comment: git clone does copy all the branches, but after that if I want to go to other branch I have to do git fetch origin <branch> && git checkout <branch>, I'm asking can I with a fetch all command, I need not to fetch origin <branch>

Comment: All you need is `git checkout <name>` (or in Git 2.23 or later, `git switch <name>`). You should, however, run `git fetch` (with no arguments at all or with the name `origin`) occasionally to pick up any *new* commits from the other Git repository, if other people are putting new commits in the other Git repository.

Comment: Note that the checkout step *creates* your own branch name. Once you have done that, it's your responsibility to update this name. The remote-tracking (`origin/*`) names get updated automatically by a `git fetch`, as they are your copies of someone else's names, but *your* names are *yours* and your `git fetch` will not update them. It updates the *remote-tracking names* as that is the remote-tracking names' purpose.

Comment: If all you want to know is, say, *what is the latest commit on the branch named `develop` over on `origin`*, one way to answer that question is to run `git fetch origin` (or `git fetch` with no argument) followed by `git log origin/develop`. You do not need a `develop` at all.

Comment: I found a cleaner solution, git branch -r and git checkout -b LocalName origin/remotebranchname

Comment: Yes, `git branch -r` lists your remote-tracking names. You don't need the `-b` in most cases—there are some where you do—but there's yet another option, which is `git checkout --track origin/<name>` which is short for `git checkout -b <name> origin/<name>`, more or less.