# How to clone a branch on GitHub?

Tags: github, git-branch

We would like to create a PR for the [Pester branch 5.0](https://github.com/pester/Pester):

[image: GitHub Pester image]

When we click on the 'Fork' button at the top right only the 'Master' branch is forked but not the `5.0` branch:
[image: GitHub Master branch]

How is it possible to get a copy of the `5.0` branch?

Comment: I think this question has been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git

Comment: When I fork the same repo, I get the `v5.0` branch. Can you try deleting the fork and try to fork again?

Comment: You have an old fork, either you can sync your fork with the upstream/main repo, or just delete your fork and fork the repo again.

Comment: Jup, deleting the old fork and doing it again fixed it for me. Thanks guys, appreciate the help.