# How can I download git branch files to local system?

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a folder like xampp/htdocs/test. Actually I need all files from specified branch(for eg:branch1) of git to this 'test' folder. I am using git clone command. But after that I got some files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a single branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Comment: Note that many web hosting sites (e.g., GitHub) offer ways to download one particular commit, or even files from within one particular commit, and Git has `git archive` to do this same sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clone the master branch. As you said that you already used `git clone <repository>`
2. Go inside the directory root by `cd <repository>`
3. Execute the git checkout command `git checkout <branch name you want to see the files>`

Comment: This does accomplish the stated goal, but in large repositories it may mean downloading many more files than are needed.