# git pull only the master branch without other branches of the repo

Tags: git

I am quite new in git and I am trying to figure out the following situation.
There is a repo in bitbucket containing the master code and some branches where a couple of colleagues are working.
After having clone that repo into a public local folder F (that is somehow available to everybody) now and again I want to pull the master in the public folder F, but I only want to pull the master. I want to avoid that in F the users can navigate to the different branches where code is still not ready for production.

obviously I tried simply git pull but this downloaded everything including the branches in the remote origin.

After going over the modifiers of git pull in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull I can not figure out which one I have to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a single branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778088/how-do-i-clone-a-single-branch-in-git)

Comment: I slighltly modify the question. The cloning is not a problem because it is a one single action at the very beginning. The difficulty starts for me when wanting to pull to a folder ONLY the master and not any other activity (branches) available in the repo

Answer (score 1):

You can do a single-branch clone:

```
git clone --single-branch --branch master <theURL>
```

Now this local repo doesn't have any remote branches except `origin/master`, and doing a `git fetch` won't automatically download any of them. People listing branches won't see them. It is possible to force a download of another branch — no power on earth can prevent that unless you want to take steps at the server side — but at least it won't be obvious that they exist.

However, having said all that, I think your goal might be mistaken. We work on a project with dozens of branches all of which belong to other companies working on their own versions of the code; only one branch belongs to us. We stay out of everyone else's branches by (get this) staying out of everyone else's branches. Git is cooperative; just tell your people to cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

You're (commonly) confusing what `git pull` does.  You can think of `git pull` as a cross between `git fetch` and `git merge`.  Specifically, `git pull` without any arguments typically does:

1. git fetch origin
2. git merge origin/main

The first one gets all the data, including remote branch labels, from the remote repository **but does not merge it into your main branch**.  So, yes all the remote branch names show up locally if you look at the output of `git branch -r`.  But, they don't change the contents of your local `main` branch.  Only the second command (`git merge`) does that and it only affects the one branch you merge in.  It would require multiple `merge`s to merge in any other branches.

So: the upshot is that `git pull` is **only merging in one upstream branch**.

(note: all the above names make assumptions about your remote names, and branch names)

Comment: perfect. OK, so in order to achieve what I want I need to AVOID that in the fetching part the branches are fetched. I only want to fetch master. I guess I fave to go then git fetch origin master and then go with the second comand. I am going to try it

Comment: Yes, the  `git fetch` command accepts a `<refspec>` argument after the remote, so you should be able to specify what you want there. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch